# Как преобразовать html код во вложенный массив?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть разметка:

```js
var elems = $( "div" );
var result = $.makeArray( elems );
console.log(result);
// массив result должен принять такой вид
var example = [
    {name: "p1", child: [
        {name: "p1.1", child: []},
        {name: "p1.2", child: [
         {name: "p1.2.1", child: []},
            {name: "p1.2.2", child: []}
        ]}
    ]}
];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>p1
  <div>p1.1</div>
  <div>p1.2
    <div>p1.2.1</div>
    <div>p1.2.2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как написать функцию, чтобы она преобразовала разметку в массив, учитывая вложенность тегов?
Конечная разметка содержит почти 27000 по разному вложенных div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var elem = document.querySelector("div"),
  example = [foo(elem)];

function foo(elem) {
  return {
    name: elem.firstChild.textContent.trim(),
    child: [].map.call(elem.children, foo)
  }
}
console.log(example)
```

```html
<div>p1
  <div>p1.1</div>
  <div>p1.2
    <div>p1.2.1</div>
    <div>p1.2.2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы мой кумир!!! Спасибо!

Comment: @user214589 выше убрал лишнее из функции